# Rule to create user on webform submission by anonymous user

Tags: rules, webforms

I'm trying to create a user with rules on webform submission by anonymous user, as the title says. I set my event (After a webform has been submitted), set my conditions and set my actions. Create a new entity of user whose name will be `[data:name-value]` and e-mail address `[data:email-value]` as seen below [image: rule to create user]. But I get **Unable to evaluate action entity_create**. However, I know `[data:name-value]` works it prints when I show it on the screen. User creation also works because a user is created when I enter fixed values. What could I be missing?

PS: I could roll my own module for this small task, but why bother when I can do it with rules?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is about what is described in "[Create entity fails when the user is anonymous](https://www.drupal.org/node/1835050)" (which is an open Rules issue, current status = RTBC).

That issue also contains a patch (attached to [comment #4](https://www.drupal.org/node/1835050#comment-6706622) of that issue), which might help as a (temporary?) work around.

**Note**: another way to get it to work, appears to be to use the token `[data:email-value-raw]`, as suggested in a comment to this answer (credits: [olisb](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17966/olisb)).

Comment: Thank you for going back in time and replying this Pierre :D I ended up rolling my own module for this, but I will definitely look at the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I just hit exactly the same problem... any chance you could share the module you wrote to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @olisb : thanks for the comment. I don't have such "module" handy. By looking at the patch (again just now), it doesn't seem to complicated. Would it help if I enhance my answer (tomorrow or so) with some instructions how you can produces such "module" with only a few lines (3 or so) of code editing?

Comment: ah! I think I have made it work by simply using the token: [data:email-value-raw]

Comment: the 'raw' bit was the answer for me!